# Easy money - write string to command using indirection instead of a file

Tags: windows, console-application, command-prompt

I know I can use

```
C:\> somecommand.exe < somefile.txt
```

To send the contents of somefile.txt to specified command, but what if, rather tan sending a file, I want to send a prepackaged string such as:

```
C:\> somecommand.exe < "this is a test"
```

I've tried that, and also:

```
C:\> somecommand.exe < echo "this is a test"
```

with no luck.

Also if you have an example for Linux/Mac that would be most helpful.

Comment: You can simply do C:\> somecommand.exe "this is a test"

Comment: That gets handled as an input argument rather than as reading from stdin unfortunately

Comment: maybe C:\> somecommand.exe "this is a test" "this is a test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [pipe `|`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) in combination with `echo` like this:

```
C:\> echo this is a test | somecommand.exe
```

I removed the quotes as they would be passed to the command as well.

Comment: Easy money.  Thanks a million.  By chance do you have a Linux/Mac example as well?

Comment: @haxor Should be the same.